# Shader wont color in Processing 3.0

Tags: glsl, shader, processing, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have been following some guides from school but cannot seem to make them work. I have written a simple sketch that draws a TRIANGLE_FAN in a 3d space. I want to apply a couple of shaders, one for the color and another for its "movement". This the code I have written so far (peasyCam is just a library for the camera control);

Sketch:

```
PShader myShader;

void settings() {
  size(640, 480, P3D);
}

void setup() {

  myShader = loadShader("frag.glsl", "vert.glsl");
  shader(myShader);
  myShader.set("tint", 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  noLights();
}

void draw() {

  background(255);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(200, 150, -100);
  beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
  {
    vertex(-100, -100, 50);
    vertex(100, -100, 0);
    vertex(100, 100, -50);
    vertex(50, 100, 0);
    vertex(-100, 50, 50);
  }
  endShape();
  popMatrix();
}
```

Shaders:

```
/////////////////////vertex/////////////////////

#define PROCESSING_COLOR_SHADER 
uniform mat4 transform;
attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec4 color;   
varying vec4 col;


void main(){
gl_Position *= (sin(0.04*gl_Position.y) + 2.0)/2.0;
col = color;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////fragment///////////////////////////
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif
varying vec4 col;
uniform vec3 tint;


void main() {
gl_FragColor = vec4(col.xyz*tint, 1); 
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The output is the shape itself, but does not seem to apply any of the shaders.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without the PeasyCam stuff?

Comment: Sure, sorry for that

Comment: I doesn't test it yet, but seems that you need assign the shader to shape per frame, not only on initialization...

You tried to call shader() inside draw() (instead setup()) already?

So far I can see, there is nothing wrong about your vertex or frag shaders...